# Regular expressions: How to make my code match the '+' character OR digits

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've just started on regex.

I'm trying to search through a short list of 'phrases' to find UK mobile numbers (starting with +44 or 07, sometimes with the number broken up by one space). I'm having trouble getting it to return numbers starting +44.

This is what I've written:

```
for snippet in phrases:
    match = re.search("\\b(\+44|07)\\d+\\s?\\d+\\b", snippet)
    if match:
        numbers.append(match)
        print(match)
```

which prints

```
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(19, 31), match='07700 900432'>
    <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(20, 31), match='07700930710'>
```

and misses out the number +44770090999 which is in 'phrases.'

I tried with and without the brackets. Without the brackets it would also print the +44 in sums like '10+44=54.' Is the backslash before the +44 necessary? Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Thanks to all!

EDIT: Some of my input:

```
  phrases = ["You can call me on 07700 900432.",
      "My mobile number is 07700930710",
      "My date of birth is 07.08.92",
      "Why not phone me on 202-555-0136?"
      "There are around 7600000000 people on Earth",
      "If you're from overseas, call +44 7700 900190",
      "Try calling +447700900999 now!",
      "56+44=100."]
```

Comment: Please include your input (or at the very least, a sample) so we can verify your observations and hopefully we will be able to offer a solution.

Comment: Looks like your match is working, but you're not printing out all the groups, but instead just the `match` object

Comment: You are passing the regex as a string, so the backslash should be doubled, like `\\+` instead of `\+`

Comment: Using raw strings (`r'...'`) would avoid that source of complexity.

Comment: BTW, personally, I suggest `[+]`, not `\+`; that way it has the same meaning across quoting contexts, rather than forcing a reader to figure out if some outer context is consuming the slash.

Comment: Does the regex need to match the 6th input as well? The `+44 7700 900190` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex the [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` does not match between  a whitespace and a plus sign.

What you could do is match either `07` or `+44` and then match either a digit or a whitespace one or more times `[\d ]+` followed by a digit `\d` to not match a whitespace at the end and add a word boundary `\b` at the end.

[`(?:07|\+44)[\d ]+\d\b`](https://regex101.com/r/gpatZW/1)

[Demo Python](http://rextester.com/QCI15932)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your regex is that the the first `\b` matches the word boundary between the `+` and the `4`. The boundary between a space and a `+` is not a word boundary. This means that it can't find `+44` after the `\b` because the `+` is on the left of the `\b`. There is only `44` on the right of `\b`.

To fix this, you can use a negative lookbehind to make sure there are no words before `+44`. Remember to put it inside the capturing group because it should only be matched if the `+44` option was chosen. You still want to match a word boundary if it were starting with `07`.

```
((?!\w)\+44|\b07)\d+\s?\d+\b
```

You can put the regex in a `r""` string. This way you don't have to write that many slashes:

```
r"((?!\w)\+44|07)\d+\s?\d+\b"
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1h87C6/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
import re
phrases = ["Hello +4407700 900432 World", "Hello +44770090999 World"]
for snippet in phrases:
    match = re.search(r"(?P<num>(\+44|07)\d+\s?\d+)", snippet)
    if match:
        print(match.group('num'))
```

**Output:**

```
+4407700 900432
+44770090999
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cover all cases by removing expected "noisy characters" from the string and simplify your regex to just `"(07|\D44)\d{9}"`. Where:

`(07|\D44)` searches for a starting number with 07 and 44 preceded by a non-numeric character. 
`\d{9}` searches for the remaining 9 digits.

Your code should look like this:

```
cleansnippet = snippet.replace("-","").replace(" ","").replace("(0)","")...
re.search("(07|\D44)\d{9}", cleansnippet)
```

Applying this to your input retrieves this:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(14, 25), match='07700900432'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(16, 27), match='07700930710'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(25, 37), match='+44770090019'>  
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(10, 22), match='+44770090099'>
```

Hope that helps.

Pd.:
The `\` before the `+` means that you are specifically looking for a `+` sign instead of "1 or more" of the previous element.

The only reason why I propose `\D44` instead of the `\+44` is because it could be safer for you as people could miss typing + prior their number. :)